# R Studio Package download not possible, over proxy server with authentication

Tags: r

R Ver.: 4.2.1
R Stduio Ver.: 2022.02.3 Build 492

We tried to install Packages from the Installer and we are not able to connect through our Proxy.
We tried the .Renviron method and almost everything found on the web and it still wont work.

Here the output of our console:

`Warning in install.packages : kann nicht auf den Index für das Repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib zugreifen: cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'`

I hope someone can help us resolve our Problem

Comment: Have you studied `help("download.file")`? In particular, this might be relevant: "Some MITM proxies present particularly in corporate environments do not work with this behavior. It can be changed by setting environment variable R_LIBCURL_SSL_REVOKE_BEST_EFFORT to TRUE, with the consequence of reducing security."